# Find the first order differential equation describing how the amount of poison changes, by interpreting this text

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

> **Translation:** A pond has $500000$ liters of water in it. The pond contains $y$ liters of poison after $t$ years. Assume that the poison is evenly distributed throughout the pond. The water flows out of the pond with the speed of one tenth per year of the actual amount of water, and new water simultaneously flows in with the same speed. New poison flows in with the new water with the speed of $1$ liter per year.
>
> Set up a differential equation describing how the amount of poison changes.

The correct answer is $dy/dt=1-0.1y$, but I don't know how to get there. I have tried to - with horrible results. I'm new to "translating" words to differential equations. How should I think? Can I get help?

Comment: Your "large" pond is a rectangular swimming pool $10\times 20\times 2.5=500$m$^3$

Comment: @Raffaele That's another way to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concentration of poison is $y/V$. So poison is lost at rate $(y/V)$*rate water leaves $= (0.1* V)*(y/V)=0.1*y$.

Poison is gained at rate 1 litre/year so change in poison $\frac{dy}{dt}=1-0.1*y$